# Как правильно соединить цикл, исключение и ввод с клавиатуры?

Tags: исключения, java

Доброго времени суток. Как сделать, как сделать чтобы введённое значение можно было ещё раз ввести.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public void start() {

        boolean programRun = true;

        while (programRun) {
            int choice = 5;
            try {
                choice = sc.nextInt();
                switch (choice) {
                    case 1:
                        //some code
                    case 5:
                        info();
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        programRun = false;
                        break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                choice = 5;
                System.out.println("Incorrect input value, please repeat");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переопределить переменную

```
public void start() {

        boolean programRun = true;

        while (programRun) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int choice = 5;
            try {
                choice = sc.nextInt();
                switch (choice) {
                    case 1:
                        //some code
                    case 5:
                        info();
                        break;
                    case 0:
                        programRun = false;
                        break;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                choice = 5;
                System.out.println("Incorrect input value, please repeat");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Переставьте местами:

```
try {                
   choice = sc.nextInt();
}
catch (Exception e) {                
   choice = 5;                               
   System.out.println("Incorrect input value, using default 5, please repeat");            
}
switch(choice) {}
```

Comment: Оно всё равно в бесконечном цикле, считает - что choice уже выбран на 5, по идеи должно предлагать по новой вводить, но не предлагает(( Можете в этом плане подсказать.

Comment: choice = sc.nextInt(); - эту строку она проскакивает, как будто уже неверное что-то хранится, хотя по новой вроде показывает, что переменная новая.

Comment: @steelhouse `nextInt()` ждет делимитер в виде пробела, надо либо читать строку целиком через `nextLine()` - потом парсить строку отдельно или закрывать scanner и открывать его заново (если хотите совсем без делимитера)